# How to convert body coordinate from Sun reference frame to Earth reference frame?

Tags: earth, the-sun, coordinates, javascript

I have the coordinates of a celestial body w.r.t. Sun , expressed as (x,y,z), at a given time.

I need to move this coordinates into a reference frame centered on Earth center, but after reading dozens of sites I am confused between Earth Centered Inertial (ECI) , Earth Centered Fixed (ECF) , ICRF,  local East, North, Up (ENU) and whatelse...  If Earth axis was not inclined, maybe it would be easy, it would be just a matter of subtracting coordinates, but unfortunately it is not that simple.

I found that satellite.js library has functions to convert from one system to another, but I do not understand which function I exactly need, and I don't want to include the full library just to use a ten-lines function...

From satellite.js documentation:

```
// You can get ECF, Geodetic, Look Angles, and Doppler Factor.
var positionEcf   = satellite.eciToEcf(positionEci, gmst),
    observerEcf   = satellite.geodeticToEcf(observerGd),
    positionGd    = satellite.eciToGeodetic(positionEci, gmst),
    lookAngles    = satellite.ecfToLookAngles(observerGd, positionEcf),
    dopplerFactor = satellite.dopplerFactor(observerCoordsEcf, positionEcf, velocityEcf);
```

Or maybe I could use this other function from CesiumJS?

> **Cesium.Transforms.computeIcrfToFixedMatrix(date)**
>
> Computes a rotation matrix to transform a point or vector from the
> International Celestial Reference Frame (GCRF/ICRF) inertial frame
> axes to the Earth-Fixed frame axes (ITRF) at a given time. This
> function may return undefined if the data necessary to do the
> transformation is not yet loaded.

so in a few words: **which are the names of the SOURCE and DESTINATION reference frames I have to take into account when passing from sun-centered to earth-centered?**

These are the data I have:

```
########################################################################################################################                                                                                                                                             
# X,Y,Z : 黄道面座標系での探査機/地球/小惑星位置，単位は[天文単位]（天文単位，太陽＝地球距離(ここでは149597870.7[km]を1とした距離）                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
#                               |----------- Spacecraft ----------|    |-----------    Earth   -----------|    |-----------  1999JU3   ----------|                                                                            |------    Maintenance Info.   ------| 
#       UTC             L+        X            Y            Z            X            Y            Z            X            Y            Z            Rs         Re         Ra       Vs       Ve     alpha    delta   Dflt   ORB_ID                           T_fp  
#                      [day]     [AU]         [AU]         [AU]         [AU]         [AU]         [AU]         [AU]         [AU]         [AU]       [10^4km]   [10^4km]   [10^4km]  [km/s]   [km/s]   [deg]    [deg] [10^4km]                                        
#--------1---------------2--------3------------4------------5------------6------------7------------8------------9------------10-----------11-----------12---------13---------14-------15-------16-------17-------18-----19----20--------------------------------21---
2020/09/01.04:59:59   2099.0  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.941759396 -0.362564266  0.000016692  1.212657811 -0.285057784  0.127795902   18391.83    4652.80     686.14   26.42    9.85    13.35    31.83 503047.8 20200825-20201002_0001_eph-ops    +0.0 
2020/09/02.04:59:59   2100.0  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.000000000  0.947521452 -0.346527920  0.000016177  1.213291467 -0.270097929  0.127370586   18350.30    4576.87     692.63   26.48    9.73    13.52    32.27 503276.4 20200825-20201002_0001_eph-ops    +0.0
```

Google translation of header:

```
# X, Y, Z: Explorer / Earth / Asteroid position in the ecliptic plane coordinate system, unit is [astronomical unit] (astronomical unit, sun = earth distance (here, distance with 149597870.7 [km] as 1))
```